# Batch file renames one file twice

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I tried to change names *.txt files, but i have a problem I can't solve.
I would like to give prefixes to *.txt files entered by user input, but the code I have adds, without knowing why, a **doubled prefix** for one file.

```
@echo off
SET /p Input=Enter prefix wanted: 
Echo You entered: "%Input%"
Pause
for %%a in (*.txt) do ren "%%a" "%Input%%%a"
```

before using the code:
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt

after using the code with prefix added by user:
test1.txt
test2.txt
testest3.txt

Do you know the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do ...
```

The problem is that when the file is renamed, the `for` looks for the next file in the directory - which could be the new name of the file.

The code I've provided builds a file list in memory, then processes the list, so it doesn't see the new name of the file.